# Pedometer package in flutter doesn't work with some devices

Tags: flutter, pedometer

I used the pedometer package version ^1.2.0 in my flutter app and I noticed that it doesn't work with some devices like Samsung A30 and others, the version I used doesn't need any permissions and it worked on my device OPPO F7 (Used Android 10) so what is the problem?

Here's the code

```
StreamSubscription<int> _subscription;
Box<int> stepsBox = Hive.box('steps');
int todaySteps;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 startListening();
}

@override
void dispose() {
 stopListening();
 super.dispose();
}

void startListening() {
_pedometer = Pedometer();
_subscription = _pedometer.pedometerStream.listen(
  getTodaySteps,
  onError: _onError,
  onDone: _onDone,
  cancelOnError: true,
);
}

void _onDone() => print("Finished pedometer tracking");
void _onError(error) => print("Flutter Pedometer Error: $error");

Future<int> getTodaySteps(int value) async {
print(value);
int savedStepsCountKey = 999999;
int savedStepsCount = stepsBox.get(savedStepsCountKey, defaultValue: 0);

int todayDayNo = Jiffy(DateTime.now()).dayOfYear;
if (value < savedStepsCount) {
  // Upon device reboot, pedometer resets. When this happens, the saved counter must be reset as well.
  savedStepsCount = 0;
  // persist this value using a package of your choice here
  stepsBox.put(savedStepsCountKey, savedStepsCount);
}

// load the last day saved using a package of your choice here
int lastDaySavedKey = 888888;
int lastDaySaved = stepsBox.get(lastDaySavedKey, defaultValue: 0);

// When the day changes, reset the daily steps count
// and Update the last day saved as the day changes.
if (lastDaySaved < todayDayNo) {
  lastDaySaved = todayDayNo;
  savedStepsCount = value;

  stepsBox
    ..put(lastDaySavedKey, lastDaySaved)
    ..put(savedStepsCountKey, savedStepsCount);
}

setState(() {
  todaySteps = value - savedStepsCount;
});
stepsBox.put(todayDayNo, todaySteps);
return todaySteps; // this is your daily steps value.
}

void stopListening() {
 _subscription.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

check for permission.

```
await Permission.activityRecognition.request().isGranted
```

this will check for permission and request permission if the permission is not allowed

```
if (await Permission.activityRecognition.request().isGranted) {
  _pedestrianStatusStream = Pedometer.pedestrianStatusStream;
  _pedestrianStatusStream
      .listen(onPedestrianStatusChanged)
      .onError(onPedestrianStatusError);

  _stepCountStream = Pedometer.stepCountStream;
  _stepCountStream.listen(onStepCount).onError(onStepCountError);
}else{
  
}
if (!mounted) return;
```

Comment: Do you know how to check this in Flutter?

Comment: that implementationnworks for flutter , only add permission_handler package

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case it would be better to ask the question directly in the lib repository, open an issue with your problem.
https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues